# When I press down on my presta valve cap when it is open why is no air coming out

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, tubeless, valves

I recently got my bike and it rides great. When I went to pump up the tubeless tires I realized that the presta valve cap isn’t letting air out when I press down on it when it is open. I looked on YouTube and didn’t find the answer to my question. Do I need a new valve cap or maybe new sealant?

Comment: When you pump it up does it increase in pressure and hold that pressure?

Comment: No the pressure stays the same. It doesn’t go up or down.

Comment: You put the pump on it, start to pump up, and your pumps gauge goes to max and you are unable to push any air into the tires?

Comment: Ya that is exactly what’s happening

Answer (score 7):

Did you unthread the small acorn nut at the top of the presta valve?

It should turn about 4 turns and once loose, you can press the top down and air should come out.

If you don't open this nut, air can't get in either.

The acorn nut won't come off, so don't force it - that breaks things.

[image]

---

> I unthread and it goes down but no air comes out.

Does your tubeless tyre have liquid sealant in it? Could be the valve is plugged because of sealant. You may need to remove the valve core using the two flats on the part of the valve just below the acorn.

Use a small spanner or pliers if nothing else is available, then poke a blunt stick in the hole, like a wooden skewer.

Comment: Thank you it worked